# DOM scripting: create elements and position them on one line

Tags: javascript, css, dom

A little background info for my page:

I have a section that always has one input field.
underneath there is an "add" button which creates more
input fields. As only one field is required on the screen the
subsequent fields are accompanied by a "delete" button which removes
the relevant input field.

Here is a screen shot of it: http://postimg.org/image/b1yz67b1f/

As you can see the buttons with "-" are placed after each input box.
I require them to go just to the right. I have tried 
display:inline on the "-"/delete button to no avail.

Code:

```
function addField(count) {


    if (count<=4){
    count++;
    var id = "tag"+count;
    var newField = document.createElement("input");
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newField.setAttribute('class', 'field');
    newField.setAttribute('id', id);

    var place = document.getElementById("tags");
    inputContainer.appendChild(newField);

    var removeId = "remove"+count;
    var remove = document.createElement("input");
    remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
    remove.setAttribute("value", "-");
    remove.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
    remove.setAttribute('id', removeId);


    remove.onclick = function () { 
        var targetInput = document.getElementById(id);
        var targetRemove = document.getElementById(removeId);
        targetInput.remove();
        targetRemove.remove();
     };

    inputContainer.appendChild(remove);
    return count;
    } 


}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you're doing wrong if you don't show your code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, I came up with the following approach :

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7UaAh/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inputContainer">
<div class="inputFieldWithButton">
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="addInput();">+</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var id = 1;
function addInput()
{
    var inputId = 'input'+id;
    document.getElementById("inputContainer").innerHTML += "<div id='"+inputId+"' class='inputFieldWithButton'><input type='text' /><button onclick='removeContainer("+inputId+")'>-</button></div>";
    id++;
}

function removeContainer(_inputId)
{
    document.getElementById(_inputId.id).remove();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is only one "+" button. There should be a "-" after every input EXCEPT the first. These are all created on the fly also.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Wrap each row in its own `<div>`:

   ```
   <div><input type="text"><button>-</button></div>
   ```
2. Put a `<br>` after each row:

   ```
   <input type="text"><button>-</button><br>
   ```

For the first, you'd have to adjust your JS to first make `<div>` tags then add the inputs inside. For the second, you can just append all of your elements as you make them, just add in the `<br>` elements.

---

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var input = document.createElement('input');
var button = document.createElement('button');

button.innerText = '-';

div.appendChild(input);
div.appendChild(button);
inputContainer.appendChild(div);
```

DEMO showing both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/7UaAh/1/

Comment: How would I do this dynamically with DOM scripting?

Comment: I added some JS to show you how to make this structure